# Use % (percent wildcard) in the recipe part of a rule

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I'd like to do something like this:

```
PHONY += bar
bar:
    $(MAKE) foo_$@

PHONY += foo_%
foo_%:
    cp somedir/%.a someotherdir/

.PHONY: $(PHONY)
```

But the `%` isn't evaluated in the recipe (the cp part).

My workaround has been to create a phony target with the same name of the file I want to use, but I would prefer a better solution:

```
PHONY += bar
bar:
    $(MAKE) foo_$@

PHONY += foo_%
foo_%: %.a
    @:

PHONY += %.a
%.a:
    cp somedir/$@ someotherdir/

.PHONY: $(PHONY)
```

Is there any way to pass the expansion of `%` to the shell command?

Comment: Are you just looking for [`$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_0024_002a) ?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for that!

Comment: Not sure what the goal of setting the `PHONY` variable is, but if you're thinking it will make the targets you've added to it phony... it won't.  There's nothing special to make about a variable named `PHONY`.

Comment: @MadScientist At the end of the file I do `.PHONY: $(PHONY)`. I'll add that line.

Comment: It's unusual (at least) to make programs and libraries into phony targets.  I'm not sure things are going to work the way you think they will.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's why I didn't like my workaround. The target looked like an actual file, but I used it to actually install the file of that name. With `$*` it doesn't look like that anymore. The behavior was and is correct, though.  The target is now called inst_lib%, and it installs the files lib$*.a, lib$*.so and lib$*.pc.